# Are you considering a ribbon type menu

Tags: kendo-ui, ribbon

Can Kendo provide an Office type ribbon menu? Including tabs for the multiple ribbons? And the little square/arrow in the lower right of a group for the advanced properties click?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo UI doesn't include a Ribbon widget yet. Part of our future plans.

Comment: Does Kendo UI include Ribbon widget now?